# Referencing an SVG filter in an external file not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I've been looking around at other questions but to no avail did I find a solution. I feel like I might not be putting the svg file in the correct location for the css/html to access it

Currently, I have this in a .svg file right next to my HTML file.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<filter id="blur">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
</filter>
</svg>
```

My css file looks like this

```
.blur {
filter: url(#blur);
}
```

I might be not giving the correct location of the blur possibly?

Comment: You should wrap your filter in a <defs> element - good practise.

Answer (score 2):

If your SVG is not in the HTML file, then you cannot just use `url(#blur)`.  You would need to use something like `url(my_svg_file.svg#blur)`.

But if I remember correctly, those sort of external file references don't work properly in all browsers anyway.  So you should move the contents of the SVG into the HTML file and leave the CSS as `url(#blur)`.

Comment: I'm trying to use blur in Firefox since it only allows for filter:url.

Comment: You can use url(#blur); and it should work.
You cannot use url(externalfile#blur). That only works in Firefox afaik.
11 years after the bug was reported, it still has not been fixed. See bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212
}

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are trying to do but .blur{} refers to the class blur, not the id blur as used in the filter. For adding CSS to the filter try #blur{} instead.

Comment: I'm adding the class .blur to a canvas in the HTML document.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying svg because filter doesn't work with the browser capabilities of Firefox V29 for the use of blur.